# capybara/selenium with rspec before :all hook

Tags: selenium, capybara, rspec2

In an attempt to reduce the number of page visits with selenium, I wanted to call the visit method from a `before :all` hook and run all my examples with a single page load. However, when I specify `before :all` vs `before :each`, the browser opens, but the url is never visited. Below is a simplified and contrived example...

```rb
describe 'foobar', :js => true do
  before :all do
    Capybara.default_wait_time = 10
    obj = Factory(:obj)
    visit obj_path(obj)
  end

  it 'should have foo' do
    page.should have_content('foo')
  end

  it 'should have bar' do
    page.should have_content('bar')
  end
end
```

When I set it to `before :each`, it works, but the page loads twice. Is this a limitation of Capybara?

Comment: See also the question [Can I use before :all with capybara?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786899/can-i-use-before-all-with-capybara)

Comment: I also need to be able to run several examples after a single page load. Any luck resolving this, or finding a workaround?

Answer (score 3):

### Cause of problem

The second example doesn't work because because Capybara resets the session after each RSpec example; the page you `visit`-ed in your `before :all` block is no longer open at that point. This an explicit behavior of Capybara. It's in the `capybara` gem, under `/lib/capybara/rspec.rb`:

```
config.after do
  if self.class.include?(Capybara::DSL)
    Capybara.reset_sessions!
    Capybara.use_default_driver
  end
end
```

I Googled around for a couple of hours and found several others struggling with this, to no avail really.

I also found that a [patch](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/commit/1476cd9c8f442211055a706fe1410db40e4639fb) that would allow Capybara to be configured *not* to reset the session after each example has been proposed ... but Capybara creator **jnicklas** [declined the pull request](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/pull/419#issuecomment-1939983).

### Solution

The quickest -- though perhaps not the best -- workable solution I've found (so far) is to [monkey-patch](https://gist.github.com/2946500) Capybara thusly:

```
module Capybara                                                                                                                                                                                  
  class << self                                                                                                                                                                                  
    alias_method :old_reset_sessions!, :reset_sessions!                                                                                                                                          
    def reset_sessions!; end                                                                                                                                                                     
  end                                                                                                                                                                                            
end
```

This just makes `reset_sessions!` do nothing when it gets called. Note: Beware of unintended side-effects! (You can always revert the `alias_method` later on in your code if you need the default resetting behavior to happen again.)

Comment: Can't seem to get this to work... A puts statement would indicate that the method is indeed being overriden, but this in conjunction with before(:all) breaks all of my specs.

I find my feature specs follow a pattern: visit page, perform actions, verify page content. Doesn't make sense to rerun that before block for each it {} block. Testing JS is slow enough as it is...I might look at the Riot test framework as it only runs setup once per context.