# not sure why changing to before all breaks this test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec2, rspec-rails

Working through the exercise of Chapter 10 of the Rails Tutorial which pertains to testing pagination of micro posts, I cannot figure out why my tests break when I do them with `before(:all)` and `after(:all)` as below.  Even just changing it to `before(:each)`, it works, so it's not the instance variable.  (although I can also get it to work not using the instance, and building up the `user` provided by `let`)

I am just trying to do this the proper way.  Doing it once (i.e., `:all`) seems right for this.  What am I missing?

I've tried `stop_and_open_page` - it shows no microposts when I use `:all`, only otherwise (with `:each`).  However, by inspecting either my instance variable or `user` (when trying it that way with the `let`) with `binding.pry` in the console - it has the microposts all times, even when I do specify `:all`.

I am thinking it's something to do with not loading the association when I use `:all`, but I can't think of a reason, since it works otherwise in the sample site and in the tests when not using `:all`.

Any ideas?

P.S. I have a side question - I have the relation set up in my `User` model like `has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy`, yet when I do these tests with the instance variable method below, I have to explicitly call `delete_all` on micro posts, otherwise they remain in the test db after the run (even though user gets deleted).  Am I missing something obvious there or does the cascading destroy not work when user is created via Factory Girl?

UPDATE: Thanks to @Jesper I caught the reason why the after(:all) wasn't removing associated microposts.  Code updated to reflect that.

```
subject { page }

let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
before { valid_signin user }

...

describe "micropost pagination" do

  before(:all) do
    @user_with_many_posts = FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "manyposts@example.com")
    @user_with_many_posts.save
    31.times { FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user: @user_with_many_posts) }
    valid_signin @user_with_many_posts
    visit root_path
  end

  after(:all) do
    @user_with_many_posts.destroy
  end

  it { should have_selector('div.pagination') }

  it "should list each micropost" do
    @user_with_many_posts.microposts.paginate(page: 1).each do |mp|
      expect(page).to have_selector('li', text: mp.content)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: The reason you dependents aren't destroyed is that `delete` skips callbacks. In other words, the callbacks needed to destroy the related models aren't ever called. Use `destroy` instead.

Comment: I see, good catch.  I remember reading that, but when I wrote the test I had "HTTP DELETE method" in my mind.  So now the after(:all) is like this, and it removes all the associated test micro posts: '    after(:all) do
      @user_with_many_posts.destroy
    end'

Comment: Ok, post updated to reflect the proper `after(:all)`.  Now if someone has some insight on why this test overall only works when it's done as `:each`...

Comment: Anybody?  I still haven't found a reason.

Comment: So how are your tests actually breaking, give us the error messages. In general, this sharing of state between the specs isn't recommended. It would be all too easy to tamper with the instance variable in a test and have this affect other tests.

Comment: When I use binding.pry or stop_and_open_page, there are no microposts beings shown for the user, so the test for the pagination div fails.

Comment: Btw, what would be the recommended way?  It takes several seconds to set up the microposts, so I don't think I would want to do it before each and every test (if, say, I was testing other things related to micropost pagination, such as page numbers, alternating colors, etc.).  This is all in its own describe block, so I am definitely happy to learn a better way to set this up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capybara resets the session between each example run, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9789326/648392

Most probably, your models are set up as expected, but the test fails because the session has been reset.

In other words, you can set up any models needed in your spec in the `before(:all)` block, but you have to move session-related stuff, like `valid_session` and `visit root_path` to a `before(:each)` block.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense and that fixed it!  From my JUnit experience I wasn't expecting that (at least the way it was set up when I used it).