# Why does rspec fail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2, rack-test

i want to check page's title through rspec. in chrome i see the expected result but rspec claim the title is empty(in chrome view source it also ok). here some code:

application.html.rb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>site | <%= yield(:title) %></title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

home.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, 'Home') %>
<h1><%= yield(:title) %></h1>
<article>
  <div><a href="#">Cameras</a></div>
  <div><a href="#">TVs</a></div>
  <div><a href="#">Laptops</a></div>
</article>
```

home_page_controller.rb

```
class HomePageController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
Reviewsite::Application.routes.draw do
   get "home_page/home"
```

home_pages_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'
feature "HomePages" do

  before { visit '/home_page/home'}

  scenario do
    expect(page).to have_selector('h1', text: "Home")
  end

  scenario do
    expect(page).to have_selector('title', text: "site | Home")
  end

end
```

and the error

```
Failures:

  1) HomePages 
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_selector('title', text: "site | Home")
     Capybara::ExpectationNotMet:
       expected to find css "title" with text "site | Home" but there were no matches. Also found "", which matched the selector but not all filters.
     # ./spec/features/home_pages_spec.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 2.52 seconds
2 examples, 1 failure
```

**EDIT:**
here is my gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.12'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.0.1'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
gem 'faker', '1.1.2'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.4'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.9'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.2.1'
gem 'mysql2'
#gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

# Dev and test gems
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.0'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '2.4.1'
  gem 'guard-spork', '1.4.2'
  gem 'spork', '0.9.2'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.6'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.3.0'
end

#only test gems
group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '2.0.2'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.1'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', '1.3.0', :require => false
  gem 'database_cleaner', '0.9.1'
  # gem 'launchy', '2.1.0'
  # gem 'rb-fsevent', '0.9.1', :require => false
  # gem 'growl', '1.0.3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capybara: How to test the title of a page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129423/capybara-how-to-test-the-title-of-a-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of

```
expect(page).to have_selector('title', text: "site | Home")
```

i changed it to

```
expect(page.html).to have_selector('title', text: "site | Home")
```

and it worked, i double checked it.
if anyone understand why page alone doesnt work, please share.

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem is about session. Capybara expire session in each `it` or `scenario` in your case.

So your `visit page` is consumed in first scenario, then the second one has no food to eat.

You can try either:

1. Remove the `before { visit '/home_page/home'}` part, and visit the page in every scenario.
2. Combine this two scenario to one. But, still, `visit` is preferred to put inside it.

Comment: i tried to put visit inside each scenario but it didnt work. plus the before command should be called each time before a scenario section, doesnt it?

Comment: Can you try rename scenario to `it`? Besides, before(:each) will be called each time. I have similar problem before, and fixed it by applying the method above.

Comment: I was using `before(:each)` before and it still not worked. Here is a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630170/capybara-selenium-with-rspec-before-all-hook

Comment: it command didnt helped, plus i tried to combine this two scenario into one scenario and it still failed moreover just run the second scenario get failed too!

Comment: i've added the controller and routes.rb to my original question.

Comment: It's weird. I think the actual page may be blank and your first test got a false passed message. Have you ever tried to see it in development mode manually?

Comment: in debug both scenarios show the good html if i check the html in the watch through page.html